# Applying Linear and Binary Searches to Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary-search, linear-search

I have to create a program that takes a user input (a number) and then the program should have that number and apply a search to the array and output the corresponding title by matching the index and the number the user inputted. However during run time, nothing happens. I have set breakers in my code and noticed a problem with the for loop (search algorithm). Please help me and let me know what is wrong is my search algorithm. What I am trying to do is use the number of that the user inputs to match a index and then output the book title that is stored in the index.

```
       private void btnFindActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:  

    // declares an array 
   String[] listOfBooks = new String [101];

   // assigns index in array to book title 
   listOfBooks[1] = "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"; 
   listOfBooks[2] = "Huckleberry Finn"; 
   listOfBooks[4] = "The Sword in the Stone";
   listOfBooks[6] = "Stuart Little";
   listOfBooks[10] = "Treasure Island";
   listOfBooks[12] = "Test";
   listOfBooks[14] = "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland";
   listOfBooks[20] = "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea";
   listOfBooks[24] = "Peter Pan";
   listOfBooks[26] = "Charlotte's Web";
   listOfBooks[31] = "A Little Princess";
   listOfBooks[32] = "Little Women";
   listOfBooks[33] = "Black Beauty";
   listOfBooks[35] = "The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood";
   listOfBooks[40] = "Robinson Crusoe";
   listOfBooks[46] = "Anne of Green Gables";
   listOfBooks[50] = "Little House in the Big Woods";
   listOfBooks[52] = "Swiss Family Robinson";
   listOfBooks[54] = "The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe";
   listOfBooks[54] = "Heidi";
   listOfBooks[66] = "A Winkle in Time";
   listOfBooks[100] = "Mary Poppins";

    // gets user input 
    String numberInput = txtNumberInput.getText();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);

    // Linear search to match index number  and user input number
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.length - 1; i++) {
        if (listOfBooks.get(i) == number) {
        txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[i]);
        break; 
        }


    }
```

*There is a problem with the listOfBooks.get in the if statement. Also I need to apply a binary search that would search the same array just using the binary method. Need help to apply this type of binary search.

**How could I make a statement that checks if the int number is equal to an index?**

Note that the following code is just an example of what I have to apply. Variables are all for example purposes:

```
public static Boolean binarySearch(String [ ] A, int left, int right, String V){
     int middle;

     if (left > right) {
         return false;
     }

     middle = (left + right)/2;
     int compare = V.compareTo(A[middle]);
     if (compare == 0) {
         return true;
     }
     if (compare < 0) {
         return binarySearch(A, left, middle-1, V);
     } else {
         return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, right, V);
     }
 }
```

Comment: you are matching book name with the input number, which makes no sense

Comment: Do you want to learn BinarySearch? If not you could use a `List` or a `Map`, it becomes very easy and searches in almost O(1) time.

Comment: How could I match the input number with the index number?

Comment: I want to learn and use BinarySearch.

Comment: Ahh! to use BinarySearch the `strings` need to be `sorted`.

Comment: if you put some non index number you will get OutOFBound Exception this is how you can check it other wise your number is fine, hoping that you write some code for this logic,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can avoid `for loop` and check condition by just giving number like this: `txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[number-1]);`

remove your code

```
// Linear search to match index number  and user input number
for(int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.length - 1; i++) {
    if (listOfBooks.get(i) == number) {
     txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[i]);
     break; 
}
```

with

```
try{
     int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);
     if(number>0 && number<101){
       txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[number-1]);
     }else{
        // out of range
     }
 }catch(Exception e){
   // handle exception here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it now. Now I need help with the binary!

Comment: for binary search your array must be in sorted order

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing `if (listOfBooks.get(i) == number)` it is wrong, you should compare: `if (i == number)`, becouse you need compare element position.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a binary search answer. Just an implementation of `HashMap`. Have a look at it.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> books = new HashMap();
books.put("abc", 1);
books.put("xyz", 2);
books.put("pqr", 3);
books.put("lmo", 4);

System.out.println(books.getValue("abc");
```

---

Using the inbuilt BinarySearch.

```
String []arr = new String[15];
arr[0] = "abc";
arr[5] = "prq";
arr[7] = "lmo";
arr[10] = "xyz";
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, "lmo"));
```

---

How to compare `Strings` using binary search.

```
String[] array = new String[4];
        array[0] = "abc";
        array[1] = "lmo";
        array[2] = "pqr";
        array[3] = "xyz";
        int first, last, middle;
        first = 0;
        last = array.length - 1;
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        String key = "abc";
        while (first <= last) {
            if (compare(array[middle], key))
                first = middle + 1;
            else if (array[middle].equals(key)) {
                System.out.println(key + " found at location " + (middle) + ".");
                break;
            } else {
                last = middle - 1;
            }
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
        }
        if (first > last)
            System.out.println(key + " is not found.\n");

    }

    private static boolean compare(String string, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(string.length(), key.length()); ++i)
            if (string.charAt(i) < key.charAt(i))
                return true;
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: LOL I wish it was that easy, but I have to apply it with the code I have put up there.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here:

`if (listOfBooks.get(i) == number) {`

is that you are matching the content of the array with the input number, which is irrelevant.

You can directly use the input number to fetch the value stored at the index.

For example:
`txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[number-1]);`

Additionally, `int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);` should be placed within try-catch block to validate input number parsing. And you can check if the input number is within the range of the array to avoid exceptions like:

```
try{

    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);

    // Linear search to match index number  and user input number
    if (number > 0 && number <=100) {
        txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[number-1]);
    } else {
    // Display error message
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle exception and display error message
}
```

And for using **binary search**, the string array need to be sorted. You can use  `Arrays.sort()` method for sorting it.
And regarding using binary search, you can use [Java Arrays Binary Search method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(byte[],%20byte))

Answer (score 0):

Your linear search code looks something like this

```
try{
txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[yourNumber]);
}
catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ie){
// prompt that number is not an index
}
catch(Exception e){
// if any other exception is caught
}
```